# PHP Type Hinting when iterate into an object

Tags: php, object, type-hinting

that's my first post on stackoverflow!

I am developing a PHP framework and I need to provide type hinting on objects.

I'm going to list an example of structure I'm using:

- a **`Database`** class, used as "entry point". This class connects to database using PDO, and has 
  an **`UserSet`** property
- a **`UserSet`** class, which extends **`Set`** (intended as a collection of users)
- a **`Set`** class with SQL-Like methods
- a **`User`** class, just with Table props

Example

**`Set`** has a select method which returns an array of users, via PDO;

```
$prepare = $this->database->prepare($this->sql);
$prepare->execute();
$prepare->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,  $this->TABLE);
return $prepare->fetchAll();
```

**`UserSet`** overrides select via **`@method`** operator like this:

`/** @method User|UserSet select() blablabla */`

In this way i get type hinting when assign select to a var

```
$result = $database->UserSet->select()
```

but $result is both of type User and UserSet and I have, in the completion code popup (Netbeans), hints from User and UserSet, while I'd like it will be of type **`UserSet`**, and have **`User`** hints only when iterate.
(something like UserSet < User >, thinking like Java)

Is it possible to reach this?

Sorry for the long post! Thank u all!

Comment: Why is your `select()` function returning different types? What does it depend on. Additionally what you are asking is more related to the IDE, Netbeans in this case. Additionally, why do you expect to see `User` hints when you iterate, what is the logic there? I am almost 99% sure that what you are asking cannot be done in Netbeans but maybe there is an alternative solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if your `select()` method is always returning `return $prepare->fetchAll();` then your return type hint in comment `@method User|UserSet select()` is wrong because `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` returns an array.

Assuming your `$this->TABLE` is `'User'` then your `select()` method returns array of `User` objects. Try hinting it like this: `@method User[] select()`.

Comment: Yes I know, PDO::fetchAll return an array. 
I was trying to create a custom collection, as UserSet, which is an array of User anyway.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question. From what I gather from the question, your `UserSet` object does not act like collection but rather more like DAO (Data Access Object). It has methods to access data like `select()` which returns arrays (collections) but does not contain any elements by it self.

Comment: And since you provided `select()` method type hinting attempt as a problem, I pointed out what was wrong with it and how it could be fixed.